# how to filter data by month in SQL or code

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

- I have data table Categories like this.

```
ID  Data    Date
1   A   2022-05-06 17:59:36
2   B   2022-05-04 13:42:55
3   C   2022-04-04 13:41:18
4   D   2022-04-04 10:46:12
5   E   2022-05-04 10:12:01
```

- But I want to get data and responses for user data.

```
month   Data
5/2022: [{
            ID: 1,
            Data: A
        },
        {
            ID: 2,
            Data: B
        }],
4/2022: [{
            ID: 3,
            Data: C
        },
        {
            ID: 4,
            Data: D
        }],
2/2022: [{
            ID: 5,
            Data: E
        }]
```

- I try group `select * from categories group by month(date)` but I don't know how to continue with this.
  please help me with how to arrange data like this.

Comment: Filtering and Grouping are not normally the same thing at all. Maybe if you show us what you actually want as a result of this query, we can better help

Comment: MySQL and MongoDB are also not the same thing, which one are you actually using

Comment: Possibly you are trying to do `select * from categories order by Year(date), month(date)` But you will never get SQL to nest items within a month, that you will have to do in your javascript code

Comment: Thanks, @RiggsFolly. data are user and service that User used my service for the gym. So I want to select by monthly to manage it. Please help me select to focus on this. This is require by client